# multi level navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please look at the image below.

Right now I am doing this with a lot of unordered lists - 5 actually. I would like to do it in a single nested ul.

I have two problems:

1. how do I create the border-bottom on the horizontal menu, if the sub menu is nested inside the horizontal menu?
2. The sub menu is made of 4 different ul's. Can I do the 4 columns using a single ul? Some menu items may fill to lines.

A pint of beer to the one who fixes either problems :)

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/333152/menu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got it, since you didn't post any code, but try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Djpsf/1/

1. Notice that you have to know the height of the submenus in orger to set the correct bottom margin on `#main`.
2. It's possible but overcomplicated and you have to reorder the items in the submenu and add some empty items.

Comment: Thats awesome. I dont think I can use it, because of the empty li's, but I sure learned a nice positioning trick.

This solution is great if someone can take care of the empty li's!

Thanks

Comment: Using empty `<li>`s is the simplest thing, but there are other ways. For example, you can set the `margin-left` style property to 150px for those items that have an empty space on their left. This has to be done via Javascript if the submenus are dynamical. Check this update: http://jsfiddle.net/Djpsf/2/

Comment: Oh I just realized. Your sub menu items are in rows not in columns :(

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said you have to reorder the items. Using multi-columns layouts can be done with some advanced CSS3 properties, but they're still unsupported by too many user agents.

Comment: yea, and I need to support ie8. Well.. I think ill use your solution to position the sub menu. But ill use 4 sub ul's instead of one. Thanks!

Comment: @tolborg If you're ok with my solution then mark my answer :)